# How do I only update specific columns in an NSTableView

Tags: objective-c

I have an NSTableView, with two columns. Whenever I add data to the table, both columns display the same data. How do I only update a specific column?

I'm doing Mac Dev btw.

This is the code I'm using:

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)streamView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn     *)messageCol row:(int)row
{
return [[stream respond] objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: please post some code so we can see what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check which column you're being asked to fill in in your implementation of `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:`.  That's why it passes you the column! Quick example, since you seem to be ignoring the "check what column you're being asked to fill in" part:

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
       objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)column 
                             row:(int)row
{
    if ([[column identifier] isEqualToString:@"A"])
        return [columnArrayA objectAtIndex:row];

    if ([[column identifier] isEqualToString:@"B"])
        return [columnArrayB objectAtIndex:row];

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: But what value should objectValueForTableColumn: have? I've tried to putting everything there but nothing seems to work!

Comment: @James, the easiest way is to set the table column's `identifier` in Interface Builder, and then test that string in your implementation.

Comment: that doesn't work though :( both columns are still displaying the same data.